# angular 4 ng2-opd-popup button options

Tags: angular

opd-popup package to create popup models. Am new to angular. How can i set buttons, i mean i need to show only single ok button in my popup.

```
 this.popup.options = {
    header: "Your custom header",
    color: "#5cb85c", // red, blue.... 
    widthProsentage: 40, // The with of the popou measured by browser width 
    animationDuration: 1, // in seconds, 0 = no animation 
    showButtons: true, // You can hide this in case you want to use custom buttons 
    confirmBtnContent: "OK", // The text on your confirm button 
    cancleBtnContent: "Cancel", // the text on your cancel button 
    confirmBtnClass: "btn btn-default", // your class for styling the confirm button 
    cancleBtnClass: "btn btn-default", // you class for styling the cancel button 
    animation: "fadeInDown" // 'fadeInLeft', 'fadeInRight', 'fadeInUp', 'bounceIn','bounceInDown'
```

};

```
 this.popup.show(this.popup.options);
```

I have tried above to set options for my popup.

Comment: remove `cancleBtnContent: "Cancel",` from this.popup.options

Comment: Still i get cancel button in my popup

Comment: are you using custom html for this ?

Comment: Yes, i got it. I have done as below

Comment: assigned showButtons to false and added button to my custom html popup